# sns: How can I add dots for outliers in jointtplot(kind=hex)

Tags: python, seaborn

I would like to generate a `sns.jointplot(x=x,y=y, kind="hex")`, but I would also like to have dots like in a scatterplot for specific outliers.

How can I accomplish such thing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach draws a scatterplot at the same spot.  Setting `zorder=0` will draw them under the hexagons.

Note that the hexagons are colored via a purposely-created colormap, with the color depending on the number of xy-values that fall into the specific hexagonal bin.  Setting `vmin=` to `2` (or higher, depending on the data), will color all hexagons with less points inside with the "under" color. Default, the under color is the lowest color in the map, but [`set_under()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap.set_under) can replace it by something else, for example `'none'` for full transparency.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

x = np.random.randn(20, 100).cumsum(axis=1).ravel()
y = np.random.randn(20, 100).cumsum(axis=1).ravel()

g = sns.jointplot(x=x, y=y, kind="hex", vmin=2)
cmap = g.ax_joint.collections[-1].get_cmap()
cmap.set_under('none')

sns.scatterplot(x=x, y=y, color='black', s=20, marker='D', zorder=0, ax=g.ax_joint)

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]